# Is there an easy way for 5 'H' and 5 'h' to be side by side

Tags: python

I am new to python. What is the code for example
String = H
String2 = h
what I want is to be like that
HhHhHhHh
Upper, lower, upper, lower.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `(String1 + String2) * 5`. Multiplying a string by an integer duplicates the string that many times.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write like this:

```
a = "H"
b = "h"
c = (a + b) * 5
print(c)
# Output: HhHhHhHhHh
```